# why does my php html onclick event execute when the page load?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code, that executes when the page loads instead of executing when the user clicks on the link.  I would like for the php function to be executed when the user clicking on the link.  Please do not give me any JS or AJAX solutions, I am only limited to PHP and HTML.

```
echo '< a href="index.php onclick="this.blur();' . somePHPfunction() .';">' . $str . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: What does `somePHPfunction()` return? What is the value of `$str`?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between **server-side** code and **client-side** code.  That is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: PHP is server side, not client side.

Comment: You do realize that PHP executes on the server, **LONG** before the html has even REACHED the client? What you want is **NOT** possible without ajax or a full-blown http round-trip.

Comment: Hint: Read the generated source.

Comment: Also - isn't `onclick` javascript?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you limited to PHP and HTML? Why can't you use JavaScript?

Comment: Guys...I knew this could not have been done w/o some JS or AJAX call, I just had to throw it out there. @putvande its a code maintenance thing

Answer (score 4):

Well the PHP is executed on the server.  So by the time the HTML gets to you, that function has already been executed.

I know you don't want to use JS or Ajax, but you must use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between server-side languages (PHP) and client-side (JS). When you run a PHP function, it is executed when the code is generated - in this case, when the html is sent to the browser. A JS function is executed when an event happens in the browser.

To fix your code, either recreate the `somePHPfunction()` in JS, or write some AJAX to call back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
echo '< a href="index.php onclick="this.blur();' . somePHPfunction() .';">' . $str . '</a></li>';
```

is server side code.  It executes `somePHPfunction()` before the HTML is even sent to the client.

The only way to fix this, is to use AJAX and (I like to use) jQuery to call that function when it's clicked.

```
echo '<a href="index.php" onclick="this.blur(); phpRequestFunction();">' . $str . '</a>';
echo '<div id="whatYouWantThePhpFunctionToChange"></div>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    function phpRequestFunction() {

        $.post("phpFunction.php", function(data) {
            $("#whatYouWantThePhpFunctionToChange").append(data);
        });
        return false;
    }
';
```

Admittedly I haven't perfectly debugged that code, but you get the idea of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want php to do something in the browser without the page refreshing or changing pages then you are out of luck.  PHP is a server side scripting language.  This means it ONLY runs on the server (e.g. the webserver itself).  It cannot run in a user's browser.

This being said, the way to make something happen can be done using just html and PHP but you need to do it using a form and POST.

Make a form with a button.  When the button gets clicked it will POST it's data to another PHP page that will then load something new.

Here is an example:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit
```

If however you wish for something in PHP to happen and then the user's browser not refresh or move to another page then you would have to use AJAX and Javascript.  Javascript for manipulating a page that has already been loaded from a server and AJAX to retrieve data using javascript from a server.